# dynamic enquiry form

Tags: functions, plugin-recommendation, forms

I'm thinking to use **Contact Form 7**  to create a simple enquiry form like : name, phone, email.

This enquiry form will be displayed  on every portfolio page.

What I want to do is to retrieve also from the user the page title from where he submitted the enquiry, because I will have more than 50 posts and I don't want to create  50 different forms for each post.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field to the form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_title" value="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
```

This will send the current posts’s title.

Comment: I didn't test it, but this should do the trick! Thank you!